# How to check AutoProtect setting for Azure Backup using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

We have about 30 SQL instances being backed up by Azure Backup. I have the needed PowerShell commands to *set* the AutoProtect policy, but there doesn't seem to be a command to *get* the AutoProtect status or policy.  Anyone got any ideas how to get this via PowerShell?

In case anyone is interested, here is the code to *set* the policy:

```
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroupName" -Name "MyRSVname"
$pol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name "MyPolicyName"
$sqlinstances = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectableItem -workloadType MSSQL -ItemType SQLInstance -VaultId $vault.ID

foreach ($SQLInstance in $sqlinstances) { Enable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupAutoProtection -InputItem $SQLInstance -BackupManagementType AzureWorkload -WorkloadType MSSQL -Policy $pol -VaultId $vault.ID }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out:

```
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroupName" -Name "MyRSVname"
$pol = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy -Name "MyPolicyName"
$sqlinstances = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectableItem -workloadType MSSQL -ItemType SQLInstance -VaultId $vault.ID
$sqlinstances | Select ServerName, IsAutoProtectable, IsAutoProtected, AutoProtectionPolicy
```